Camera aspect ratio changed when browser is resumed from home page on iPhone

I have a web application that opens front camera and displays feed.
Camera is active and user goes back to iPhone's home screen (making browser deactivated / visibility changed to not-visible)
When user resumes application, camera is shown in different aspect ratio - I guess switched between landscape to portrait mode.

I tried following things - none worked

Open camera with specific aspect ratio
Opening camera without any constraints.
Opening camera with fixed constraint.

Here is sample camera application I created for your reference (attaching code as jsfiddle did not allowed me to open camera).
Open this page locally / or secured link on iPhone. Start camera and check aspect ratio. Go to iPhone's home. Switch back to application. Notice camera and its aspect ratio logged.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Camera Feed with Settings</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        video {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            width: 500px;
            height: 375px;
        }

        div {
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

        button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="startCameraBtn">Start Camera</button>
    <video id="videoFeed" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <div id="trackSettings">Camera settings will appear here.</div>

    <script>
        const startCameraBtn = document.getElementById('startCameraBtn');
        const videoFeed = document.getElementById('videoFeed');
        const trackSettingsDiv = document.getElementById('trackSettings');

        let mediaStream = null;

        // Function to display video track settings
        function displayTrackSettings() {
            if (mediaStream) {
                const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                const settings = videoTrack.getSettings();
                trackSettingsDiv.textContent = JSON.stringify(settings, null, 2);
            }
        }

        // Start the front camera
        startCameraBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
                mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'user' } });
                videoFeed.srcObject = mediaStream;
                displayTrackSettings();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing camera: ', error);
                trackSettingsDiv.textContent = 'Error accessing camera.';
            }
        });

        // Update settings when page visibility changes
        document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
            displayTrackSettings();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



What is the desired behaviour?

Aspect ratio should remain same. iPhone is changing it just after resuming.
